# Using phantomjs to make ajax calls using extjs proxy on local file

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, extjs, jasmine, phantomjs

I have a basic EXT JS store that uses a proxy to access a local json file.

e.g.

```
...
proxy: {
    type: 'ajax',
    api: {
        read: 'data/mydata.json'
    },
    reader: {
        type: 'json',
        root: 'datas',
        successProperty: 'success'
    }
} 
...
```

I want to use Maven, Jasmine and PhantomJS to build and test my project with Atlassian Bamboo (my CI server).

When I execute PhantomJS locally, like so:

```
$ phantomjs "c:\phantomjs-1.6.1\examples\run-jasmine.js" run-tests.html
```

I get the following output:

```
'waitFor()' finished in 422ms.
 4 specs, 2 failures in 0.075s
```

This is happening because PhantomJS can't manage to load local files using *file://* protocol for the EXT JS proxy.

I'm following [this](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/guide/testing) example, and am wondering whether it's possible to mock my proxies response so that I can use PhantomJS locally (on my Bamboo server) with the test html file, rather than having to host the project in a web server like Apache (an external dependency I will have to manage with Maven).

If not, are there any other mechanisms (built into Jasmine, PhantomJS, or otherwise), that I can use to achieve this?

Comment: FYI, I'm using phantomjs 1.6.1.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It actually *is* possible to do XHR with PhantomJS when loading from the file system!

Straight from [the PhantomJs wiki](http://code.google.com/p/phantomjs/wiki/Interface):

```
--web-security=[yes|no] disables web security and allows cross-domain XHR (default is yes)
```

Also see [this issue report for PhantomJs](http://code.google.com/p/phantomjs/issues/detail?id=291) which might shed some light on this topic.

Sencha's 'sencha create jsb' command uses PhantomJs (and Ext.Loader uses XHR) and it supports loading from the file system.

```
name: 'app-entry',
alias: 'a',
description: 'The file or URL path to your application\'s HTML entry point',
```

Checkout `[senchasdktools]/compat/command/src/modules/GenerateJSB.js` and `[senchasdktools]/compat/command/scripts/phantomjs-jsb.js`.

I don't see anything related to the mentioned `web-security` switch though. Maybe they use a custom phantomJs build.

**UPDATE**
This code fragment allows XHR requests to the file system. Tested with the latest version of phantomJs (1.6.1/Windows):

```
var page = new WebPage();
page.settings.localToRemoteUrlAccessEnabled = true;
```

**UPDATE2**
This is a working example.

Put everything in the same folder, add a `test.txt` file with some content, then run

```
phantomjs script.js test.html
```

phantomjs script (script.js):

```
var fs = require('fs');

var appLocation = phantom.args[0];

var page = new WebPage();

page.settings.localToRemoteUrlAccessEnabled = true;
page.settings.ignoreSslErrors = true;

page.onConsoleMessage = function(message, url, lineNumber) {
    console.log((url ? url + " " : "") + (lineNumber ? lineNumber + ": " : "") + message);
};

page.onError = function (msg, trace) {
    console.log(msg);
    trace.forEach(function(item) {
        console.log('  ', item.file, ':', item.line);
    });
    phantom.exit(1);
};

if (!/^file:\/\/|http(s?):\/\//.test(appLocation)) {
    appLocation = 'file:///' + fs.absolute(appLocation).replace(/\\/g, '/');
}

page.open(appLocation, function(status) {
    if (status !== 'success') {
        error("Failed opening: '" + appLocation + "'. Please verify that the URI is valid");
    }

    page.evaluate(function() {
        window.onerror = function(message, url, lineNumber) {
            console.log((url ? url + " " : "") + (lineNumber ? lineNumber + ": " : "") + message);
        };

    });

    timer = setInterval(function() {
        console.log('Timeout!');
        phantom.exit(1);
    }, 2000);
});
```

Html file (test.html):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html class="x-border-box x-strict">
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    try {
        xhr.open('GET', 'test.txt', false);
        xhr.send(null);
    } catch (e) {
        console.log('cross origin?');
    }

    console.log('status', xhr.status);
    console.log('response', xhr.responseText);

    </script>
</head>
<body class="x-body">
</body>
</html>
```

**Chrome and --disable-web-security and ExtJs**

I am actually using `--disable-web-security` as startup parameter to Google Chrome to run my webapp form the filesystem during development and it works there (no other Chrome processes must be running when starting Chrome). 
Chrome will display an alert message stating that you are using an unsupported option (yellow notification bar at the top).

However, for Ext to work in a setup like this I required an additional patch to Ext.Connection in order to fix two issues: 
(1) xhr.status is always `0` when loading a file system resource. Ext does not consider this status code as `successful`. There is code dedicated to handling this when Ext is running in PhantomJs - that's why it should work there.

(2) Chrome failed loading file system resources when the URL contains a query string. I override the Connection class to strip all url params when in filesystem mode.

Comment: This is exactly why I raised this question... the --web-security switch doesn't seem to work as expected using the run-jasmine.js example. I haven't had time to focus on this yet, so I'll take another stab soon and report back.

Comment: I updated my answer to provide sample code taken from the Sencha script. This supports XHR requests to the filesystem (with the document served from the filesystem as well)

Comment: Still having issues using run-jasmine.js. For the store in my original question, I have a [basic spec](https://gist.github.com/3462131). I'm passing `--config=config.json` to phantomjs which includes [this](https://gist.github.com/3462159), and have validated their application to `page.settings` in run-jasmine.js.

Comment: I created a basic script using synchronous xhr, thinking there must be a difference using the extjs proxy object... still getting error: _XMLHttpRequest cannot load file://test.js/pop.txt. Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP._; using both `--web-security=no` and `--local-to-remote-url-access=yes`.

Comment: Updated the answer with a working example of a phantomjs script that launches a html file that will load a text file via XHR

Comment: works, thanks. There's an error in your code - instead of args[0], you want args[1].

Comment: I'm still not entirely sure why I can't do the xhr call in the phantomjs script? If you run your example without the `page.settings.localToRemoteUrlAccessEnabled = true;` it still works.

Comment: re: args[0] vs args[1]. args[0] works for me. Seems that phantomjs strips the original first argument (the script file) from the args array. When running `phantomjs script.js test.html` calling `phantom.args[0]` inside the script.js file will return `test.html`.

Comment: re: localToRemoteUrlAccessEnabled - you are correct, I can observe the same behavior. Just by considering the naming of this variable it seems that it doesn't apply to our use-case scenario (localToLocal).

Comment: re: 'cant do the xhr call in the phantomjs script' - Are you by any chance doing the xhr call *outside* the phantomjs *page* context. The way I understand phantomjs is that you have to instantiate a 'page', then use `page.evaluate` to run your code in the context of the browser.

Comment: Yes, you're correct about using `phantom.args[0]`. Re: `localToRemoteUrlAccessEnabled=true` I always thought the correct property was `webSecurityEnabled=false` for same origin errors... it just doesn't ever seem to work. This is getting away from my original problem with the extjs `Proxy`, so I'll try and get this working tomorrow with that code.

Comment: I find the situation confusing as well. I am not sure that the docs are in sync with the actual behavior of phantomjs. Also, there are obviously differences between defaults in Chrome and defaults in phantomjs. My observation is that phantomJs does not need any switch to do XHR to the file-system (when running from a file-system URL).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15876/discussion-between-wulfgar-pro-and-mistaecko)

Answer (score 4):

that is browser, and WebKit, restriction (security) and there is no way to bypass except if you run your own webserver. There is easy way with nodejs. Its about few lines of code to run server on some port on local machine.

Just create server.js as below and run it with `node server.js` before you run phantomjs

```
var http = require('http');
var fs=require('fs');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
  res.end(fs.readFileSync(__dirname + req.url, 'utf8')); 
}).listen(3000, '127.0.0.1');
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:3000/');
```

Keep this file in project root or update line

```
res.end(fs.readFileSync(__dirname + req.url, 'utf8'));
```

__dirname is path of folder in which server.js lives and is set by node process....

now you can keep data/*.json or even create mock data in node ;)

## ===Update====

After reading PhantomJS documentation I found that you can do same as above without nodejs. Apparently, PhanotmJS has all above modules included

Consider to check:

- http://code.google.com/p/phantomjs/wiki/Interface#WebServer_Module
- http://code.google.com/p/phantomjs/wiki/Interface#Filesystem_Module

And you will be good to go.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote 2 repos for dealing with ExtJS 4 for unit testing using Karma test runner/ Jasmine 1.x and 2.0 versions and dealing with Async Issues: here they are: https://github.com/cgauthier/karma_jasmine_1_extjs4 and https://github.com/cgauthier/karma_jasmine_2_extjs4.